# AS3 Flash - Adding movieclip to stage with Actionscript not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

For some reason unknown to me, I am unable to add a movieclip to stage or my document class.

This is what I have:

```
var testShard:blockshards = new blockshards();
addChild(testShard);
```

Nothing happens but the code for blockshards is executed (I see it in output).

When I manually add it in the .fla file it works.

Does anyone know why? When I replace blockshards with another movieclip it works fine.

Here's my blockshards.as:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class blockshards extends MovieClip{
        var framesToDie:uint = 30;
        var xspeed:Number = 0;
        var yspeed:Number = 0;
        public function blockshards() {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntFrm);
            xspeed = 2 - Math.random() * 4;
            yspeed = -5;
        }
        public function onEntFrm(e:Event){
            framesToDie--;
            if(framesToDie <= 0){
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntFrm);
            }
            alpha -= 0.03;
            x += xspeed;
            y += yspeed;
            yspeed += 0.2;
            xspeed *= 0.98;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Class names should start with capital by convention.

Comment: also would it kill you to type the 4 extra letters of "onEnterFrame"

Comment: @Adam Harte: I thought onEnterFrame was a reserved function?

Comment: Then it will be the registration problem.

Comment: `onEnterFrame` was a reserved function name in AS2.  In AS3 you can use it, but the compiler will issue a migration warning that will not affect your ability to compile.

Comment: With AS3 I prefer to name my event listener methods a bit more descriptive e.g. `handleEnterFrame`

Comment: @Adam Harte "`handleEnterFrame`"? blergh lol.

Comment: @Taurayi Yip that's right. Actually mostly I use `enterFrameHandler`

Comment: @Adam Harte yh, I remember being torn between **[eventType]Handler**, and **on[eventType]** but I tend to include the object name when I'm naming my event handlers, so it would look like this **on[objectName][eventType]**. Comparing that to **[objectName][eventType]handler**, the former wins hands down(in my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code to another function and it worked somehow without changing anything to do with blockshards.. very weird

Answer (score 2):

You should not execute code directly on your display objects constructors, it is always a better idea to place a check for the sage first, other ways, weird things happen.

```
public function blockshards() {
     if ( stage ) _init( );
     else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _init );
}

private function _init( e:Event = null ):void {
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _init );
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntFrm);
    xspeed = 2 - Math.random() * 4;
    yspeed = -5;
}
```

Same thing on your document class' constructor.

Comment: @Adam Harte except for the `_init()` that seems to be all goliatone. I guess everyone has their own preferences but I don't think he should use underscores on private methods, he should only use them on private properties.

Comment: @Taurayi I totally agree, except I even dislike underscores on private properties, unless you are use get/set methods

Comment: @Adam Harte: Well, it's a matter of preferences. Got some code conventions early on at work, everybody had different approaches and backgrounds but we settled for this one. And I like my private properties and methods both to be distinguished from public ones.

Comment: @Taurayi: To say that "he should only use them on private properties" sounds a bit too much. Reminds me of the _tomayto_ vs. _tomahto_ dilemma and how effervescent some ppl get on that subject. I think it's a bit snobbish, rally.

Comment: Actually, the only _bad practice_ that I would point out of the PO's code, is that he does not declare props. as public/private...

Comment: @goliatone "**I don't think** he should use underscores on private methods", personal opinion, however "snobbish"...I think its a bit snobbish to call someone snobbish, rally. Childnishness aside, I honestly rarely(if ever) see someone use an underscore for a private method, thats why I felt like pointing it out.

Comment: @Adam Harte my problem with not using underscores is that it can be a hassle to keep track of which properties are private and which are public, although admittedly not using underscores is a little more pleasant on the eyes. Well one thing is for sure, nobody should use $ as a prefix for parameters, those are god awful, lol, I'm just asking for trouble with that one :)

Comment: @Taurayi Personally I think using underscores is horrible on the eyes. Don't know why people feel the need to decorate there code. For one you should know what your code does, and the variables your using (if its not your code, then you should read it). Secondly, you IDE should take care of most of this issue for your. Third, why do you even need to know if a property is private or public internally?

Comment: @Adam Harte well simply put it makes the code more clear and readable for others as well as youself(especially if your reviewing or revising past code). What your suggesting is having to go the extra mile when you don't really have to.

Comment: @Taurayi:hehe, sorry! I was not calling you a snob!It was really meant for the _tomayto_ vs _tomahto_ thing...we do agree on the $parameters, thou ;) Anyways, my point was that code conventions are a (useful) formality but really a matter of personal preferences at the end of the day. As long as they are used homogeneously throughout a shared code base- project, framework, etc...

Comment: @Adam Harte: Something I don't miss is the _kinda_ Hungarian notation that you needed on the flash IDE to get code completion...suffixing variable names with underscore and the two letters signifying the type: log_tf, main_mc, etc...

Comment: @Adam Harte:"Third, why do you even need to know if a property is private or public internally?" For once, I really don't like to qualify my private variables with `this` to distinguish from parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have used **linkage Properties** to create the `blockshards` class.

So it may be **registration point** problem. So please check the registration point of the `MovieClip`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing drawn in or attached to your movieclip. Your clip will be there but shown empty!

Edit: Apparently this is already known by you. And I don't know Flash :-) But here is a link that gives you a step by step description of exporting movieclips for ActionScript:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html